# Printing progress bar on a console without the use of for -loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script written in python, where I have a statement:

```
Process.open() //some parameters
```

Which executes a command and  puts the output on the console ,

where I do not know the time taken to execute the above statement , the above statement will be called by a function to complete a series of command execution and there is no for loop used at all like in typical examples in “progress bar in python examples”.

Now , my question is it possible to print the progress bar to show the completion of progress like 1..100% in python for this scenario?

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you don't know how much time it will take you can't do it. Period.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subprocess` module allows you to attach pipes to the stdout and stderr of your spawned process. It's a bit complicated but if you know the output of that process very well, you can poll the output generated through the pipe at specific intervals and then increment a progressbar accordingly. Then again, if that process generates console output anyway, why not implement a progressbar there?

Edit to show how this could be done. `args` is a list with your command and its arguments.

```
import subprocess
sub = subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=-1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
while sub.poll() is None:
    output = sub.stdout.read() # get all of current contents
    if output:
        # ... process output and decide how far the process has advanced
        # ... advance your progressbar accordingly
    else:
        time.sleep(1E-01) # decide on a reasonable number of seconds to wait before polling again
if sub.returncode != 0:
    err = sub.stderr.read()
    # ... decide what to do
```

If you can modify the sub process I suggest you do the progress there.

Comment: As you said, If I am calling console.log(Process.open()) ; is it possible to print the status bar for this line of statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what `console.log` is in your comment, is it a `logging.Logger`?

Comment: Yes...similar to logging.info, which will basically output the results to the console after calling a function which contains the statement Process.open()